# How to make middle nested div scroll and top and bottom nested div maintain position fixed?

Tags: html, css, angular

I have a parent container containing 3 inner divs. I only want the middle inner div to scroll horizontally. Here is my code:

```
<div class="outer-container">
    <div class="top-inner-container">
        xoxoxoxoxoxo    
    </div>
    <div class="middle-inner-container">
        only this must scroll ===> yeah yeah yeah        
    </div>
    <div class="bottom-inner-container">
        oxoxoxoxoxox
    </div>
</div>
```

```
.outer-container {
    height: 470px;
    position: relative;
}
.top-inner-container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 70px;
}
.middle-inner-container {
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 1480px;
    background-color: grey;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    position: absolute;
    top: 60px;
    left: 0px;
    height: 340px; 
    display: flex; 
}
.bottom-inner-container {
    position: absolute;
    // background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    top: 404px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

I've tried many variations and this is the best I get but here all 3 divs scrolls.
Any idea how to fix this?

**Update:**
To reiterate. Instead of just having the middle div scroll horizontally all 3 divs scroll. The scroll bar appears on the parent instead of just on the div with class middle-inner-container. The desired result is where only the div with class middle-inner-container scrolls horizontally.

**IMPORTANT**
Ignore the vertical scroll for now. I just realize with more content the vertical scroll works. I'm not concern with vertical scroll just horizontal scroll. Top and bottom should not scroll horizontally, only the middle div should scroll horizontally. The "xoxoxoxoxo" should always be visible on the screen when scrolling horizontally. Thank you.

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j58kch6u/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the middle container horizontal scroll working by adding `white-space: nowrap;` to  the `.middle-inner-container` class.

the css looks like so:

```css
.outer-container {
    height: 470px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    .top-inner-container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 70px;
    }
    .middle-inner-container {
        white-space: nowrap;
        background-color: grey;
        overflow-x: scroll;
        height: 340px;
        .block {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    }
    .bottom-inner-container {
        // background-color: #fff;
        width: 100%;
        top: 404px;
        left: 0px;
    }
}
```

remember to add the class block to each subsection in the middle div.

Comment: white-space: nowrap has no effect

Comment: As per my understanding that you want to make the middle div horizontal scroll working by adding more text it's just be wrapped by the container and x-scroll not working. Could you clarify the problem more thankfully

Comment: I clarified in my update. Look at my updated question. Thank you.

Comment: I'm going to add content in the middle section that will take up a lot of horizontal space. This middle container should be the only scrobble (horizontal) container and the top and bottom should always be visible on the screen. That is what I tried with position fixed but top, middle and bottom scrolls.

Comment: I added huge text content and all three div still visible but the middle container is vertically scroll working. you want to make it scroll horizontally instead of vertical within the middle  container height you set , is it right?

Comment: You got it. 3 divs stacked on top of each other. Top one no scroll (vertical or horizontal). Middle div scroll only horizontal but not vertical. Bottom div no scroll (vertical or horizontal). Reason: Top and bottom always visible. Middle scrolls horizontal yes.

Comment: Ignore the vertical scroll for now. I just realize with more content the vertical scroll works. I'm not concern with vertical scroll just horizontal scroll. Top and bottom should not scroll horizontally, only the middle div should scroll horizontally. The "xoxoxoxoxo" should always be visible on the screen when scrolling horizontally. Thank you.

Comment: Try ```white-space: pre;``` in the middle div, does it solve it ?

Comment: I added a fiddle. Test on there.

Comment: Congratulations with your 1000! :)